# Issues with starting tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat

I have two tomcat servers available in my windows 8 machine.Its a 64 bit m/c. The location of the tomcat servers are

```
server1 : C:\Tomcat6.0\bin
server2 : C:\Tomcat61.0\bin
```

when i try to start the tomcat6.exe from server1 location, it by default starts the tomcat6.exe available in the server2 location. I have checked the environment variables as well and there is no CATALINA_HOME variable set in there. Im trying to run tomcat6.exe (from the server1 location) via the command prompt. There is a tomcat service available in services.msc and it points to the tomcat6.exe file in server2 location

I tried to execute the tomcat6.exe(via command prompt)available in the server1 location. The tomcat6.exe gets executed but it executes the files that is located in the server2 location.The log folder available in the server2 location also gets updated

**Steps taken to fix the issue**

- Opened command prompt, navigated to the server1 location of tomcat. Manually set the 'CATALINA_HOME' to server1 location and re ran the tomcat6.exe file. But still the file in server2 location was getting executed.
- Checked the environment variables & checked the path as well there is no default  'CATALINA_HOME' being configured.

I need help to run the tomcat server located in the server1 location. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the exe file and most likely it reads its configuration from the registry. Start Tomcat using C:\Tomcat6.0\bin\startup.bat instead, that should work.

Comment: There is no startup.bat file in the tomcat6 version that i have in my m/c

Comment: Right. There is one in the latest Tomcat 6 zip for Windows that you can download from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi though.

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your environment path

Create New Environment Path

**CATALINA_HOME="C:\Tomcat6.0"**

Edit Path Variable at end of line

Path=;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin